# Create Sharepoint Site structure dynamically

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, site-collection, visual-web-part, publishing-page

I want to add a user interface where user create a Sharepoint SiteCollection for each project. 
For example we have textbox where we can put a name of the project, it will be also the name of the siteCollection, when he hit a button, a site collection is created, with 3 sites, their pages and webparts (same architecture for all the created site collection). 
My question is : 
is this need possible to be realised, if yes could you please give me some steps to perform.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you say you wan to add user interface, do you mean a web page or a windows form ?

In both case you would have to use SERVER object model to create site collection pragmatically..This page/windows application has to run from windows server where SharePoint is installed...

http://zabistop.blogspot.in/2008/07/programmatically-creating-site.html

Other option could to be to use powershell script and somehow execute this powershell script on hit of button.

https://blog.mastykarz.nl/programmatically-creating-sites-site-collections-custom-web-template/

Some discussion on this is on below link

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3e8d8f07-ca7e-4394-944f-79fed34ea7c1/create-site-collection-programmatically?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: @Siddarth thankx for your help, I was thinking to add textbox , for the name of the site collection, and a button to create it. I will read your link. the problem is how to create the pages and add the webpart already developped in each site collection

Comment: MAybe there's a way to save site collection (with his sites, pages, Webparts) as template ?

Comment: yes..you can always save site a template which includes content...but if any custom web part developed has to be deployed first on site collection/web application else web part won't work......!